# Best way to index numpy array to retrieve data by rowID and not index

Tags: python, numpy

In my application I have a large set of node saved as a nx3 ndarray of floats.

I am reading an manipulating geometry files, and as such, each node is usually referred by an ID. So for example, after I load all my nodes, I will load my quadrilateral elements, and each element is defined by 4 ints, refering to the ID of each corner node.

The issue is that there is a difference between the node ID, and the node index (in my ndarray). So every time I want to do something on the element, and I need its node coordinates, I would first need to search an array containing the node IDs for a match, and then retrieve the node coords at that index. This would be extremely slow.

To improve the efficiency of the code, I create an indexing dict when I first load the nodes. The indexing dict maps the nodeID to the node index on the array, and makes it much faster.

This indeed works much much faster. The only thing I don't like about the approach is that I always need to use a python loop to access more than one element. And because I have to frequently go back and forth on these two representations, this is a bit slow.

Is there a better/faster way to handle this indexing, and then the retrieving of the data I want?

```
import numpy as np

# Dummy data for example purposes
nx, ny = 4, 5
id2index = {x:xi for xi,x in enumerate([0,1,2,3,100,101,102,103,50,51,52,53,200,201,202,203,1000,1001,1002,1003])}
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,nx), np.linspace(0,1,ny))
nodeCoords = np.vstack( (x.reshape((nx*ny,)), y.reshape((nx*ny,))) ).T
# References to nodeIDs, and not node indexes
myElems = np.array([ [0,1],[101,100],
                     [101,102],[52,51],
                     [52,53],[203,202],
                     [203,200],[1000,1003]])

# ---------------------------------------

# Example of retrieving element coordinates, but with a slow "for-loop"
elemCornerCoords=np.zeros((myElems.shape[0], 4))
for ei, e in enumerate(myElems):
    elemCornerCoords[ei, :2] = nodeCoords[ id2index[e[0]] ]
    elemCornerCoords[ei, 2:] = nodeCoords[ id2index[e[1]] ]
```

Comment: Is there a reason the node numbers are not continuous? It's strange that you don't have a node 5, but go from 3 to 50. How are they numbered?

Comment: If there is some defined way to convert a node number to an index (not a dictionary mapping but a function, like the node number divide by 10 plus 1 gives the index), then you can create an intermediate function that you apply to the node numbers and converts that array of node numbers to indices.

Comment: What is the largest node number that you will ever use?

Comment: The nodes are not continuous due to the origin of the data. In geometry and simulation files this is not uncommon, and modules from different sources are commonly used, and so the nodeIDs are kept very high and far apart.

Comment: The highest nodeID can be very very high (orders of magnitude higher than number of nodes), so using a np.zeros((highestNodeId,1),dtype=int) as a mapping array is not suitable.

Comment: And there is no particular logic to the nodeID, it can be considered random, as it is a result of the history of the data, and many users before.

Comment: Sounds like the hashing of `nodeID` with dict is the most efficient in memory and individual lookup.  But you can only do one at a time.

Comment: I agree with @hpaulj. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but if you are constantly querying the dictionary for the same elements, you would benefit from doing that query once to build an array of indices for that element and then use that to result whenever you need that element.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the solution was not very optimizable. I did find the numpy vectorize function, which I am not sure if it speeds up the code, but it definitely cleans it up significantly. So I can vectorize my index dict:

```
v_id2index = np.vectorize( lambda id: id2index[id] )

elemCornerCoords[:,:2] = nodeCoords[ v_id2index(myElems[:,0]) ]
elemCornerCoords[:,2:] = nodeCoords[ v_id2index(myElems[:,1]) ]
```